# Pointers to Pointers to Pointers (Error: Expression must have classtype)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dynamic

I'm having some trouble with multi-layer pointers. Basically I'm reading point locations from a file and using them to map out polylines.

I'm trying to create a dynamically allocated data structure that will change depending on the information contained in the file.

Each file is structured like this.

```
29 // number of polylines in the whole file
3 // first polyline, number of points in it
32 435 // first coordinate where x = 32 and y = 435
15 200
100 355
10  // second polyline, number of points in it
245 35
330 400
```

and so on etc.

I created a struct with x and y ints to hold the coordinates for each point

```
struct coordinates{
  int x;
  int y;
};
```

I want to basically create a data structure like this ...

```
Pointer --> array w/ num of polys
             |      |      |
             |      |      |
             v      v      v
           poly0   poly1  poly2       // arrays with coordinate structs
            x1,y1   x1,y1  x1,y1
            x2,y2   x2,y2  x2,y2
            x3,y3   x3,y3  x3,y3
```

Here's what my code looks like

```
coordinates *** dinoPoints;

struct coordinates{
      int x;
      int y;
 };

void myInit(void){...} // just has initialization stuff for the draw window

void loadDino (char * fileName)
{
  fstream inStream;
  inStream.open(fileName, ios ::in); // open the file
  if(inStream.fail())
  return;

  GLint numpolys, numlines; // these are just regular ints

  inStream >> numpolys; //reads in number of polys

  //dynamically allocates the number of polys in file to datastructure
  dinoPoints = new coordinates**[numpolys]; 

  for(int j = 0; j < numpolys; j++){  // read each polyline

      inStream >> numlines;  // read in number of lines in polyline

      dinoPoints[j] = new coordinates*[numlines];

      for (int i = 0; i < numlines; i++){  // allocate each set of coords
          dinoPoints[j][i] = new coordinates;

          // read in specific point coordinates
          inStream >> dinoPoints[j][i].x >> dinoPoints[j][i].y;
      }
   }        

   inStream.close();
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    drawDino();   // draws the dinosaur on the screen
}

//still writing this function. Calls myDisplay through glutDisplayFunc()
// and also calls loadDino with filename passed as a parameter

void main(int argc, char **argv){...}
```

So for some reason it's giving me "expression must have classtype" errors on the line

inStream  >>  dinoPoints[ j ][ i ].x   >>  dinoPoints[ j ][ i ].y;

Also normally the IDE (Visual Studios 2010) will show the different elements of a data structure after a period is typed, but after typing "dinoPoints[ j ][ i ]. " it doesn't show up with any contained elements to select from, which means it doesn't even know what I'm talking about in regards to dinoPoints[ j ][ i ]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I feel like i'm missing something in regards to how the multilevel pointers work, but I'm not sure exactly what.

Comment: The secret of handling multi-layer pointers is to avoid them.~

Comment: Hello, J. Welcome to stackoverflow. I see you posted a very nearly complete program. Thank you for the context. To make future questions even easier to answer, please include a minimal, **complete** program. For more information about why that is important, and how to do it, see http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a triple-layered pointer. You need three de-references in there. You've only got two with `dinoPoints[j][i]`- the result of that expression is a *pointer*.

Not to mention the horrendous unsafety of what you're doing. Use a `vector<vector<vector<coordinates>>>` for this- it's safer and easier to understand.

Comment: Even if you want to avoid vector, at the very least you should typedef each level of pointer.  It makes things clearer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wasn't aware that you could layer vectors like that.

Is it considered unsafe due to the chance of memory leaks?

Comment: The way the data-structure is described looks like a 2D-array to me, not a 3D-array ... so would you really want either a triple-pointer or a triple-nested vector?  The only reason I see for a triple-pointer would be to allow for "moveable" memory without a function having to worry about passing a pointer by reference using the address-of operator...

Comment: @J_Xlin: In general, consider it impossible for the standard library containers to memory leak.  Nesting vectors is completely safe.

Comment: That would only happen if you store a non-pointer data-type in a standard container ... STL containers don't "own" pointers stored in them, so they won't call `delete` on them either, creating memory leaks.

Comment: @J_Xlin: You're vastly, vastly less likely to encounter memory leaks using Standard containers than raw pointers. In fact, in the general case, it's *impossible* to leak memory that way, whereas it's extremely possible to encounter problems. All good C++ coding standards use resource-owning classes very extensively and virtually never use raw pointers.

Comment: I ended up using the vector template. I've used pointers a lot in my lower level computer science, especially in regards to linked lists which is why I first thought to use raw pointers. I will keep this in mind next time though.

Answer (score 1):

Your data-structure actually appears to be a 2D-array rather than a 3D-array.  Thus in order to mirror the data-structure you're describing, rather than a triple-pointer for your array, you only really need a double pointer, or a `coordinate**`.  This is because your `coordinate` variable only needs to point to an array of pointers that each point to an array of coordinates that represent your polygons.  From what I can see, there is no "polygon" type, but rather you are simply representing an array of coordinates as a polygon.  Thus, this is only a two-dimentional array, and your `dinoPoints` variable only needs to point to a 2-dimensional array, making it a pointer-to-pointer (where the second pointer points to a dynamic array), not a triple-pointer.

To allocate this properly, you would do the following:

step 1) change

```
dinoPoints = new coordinates**[numpolys];
```

to

```
dinoPoints = new coordinates*[numpolys];
```

because you only need an array of pointers that will each point to an array of `coordinates`.

step 2) change

```
dinoPoints[j] = new coordinates*[numlines];
```

to

```
dinoPoints[j] = new coordinates[numlines];
```

Now when you call `inStream >> dinoPoints[j][i].x >> dinoPoints[j][i].y;`, it should work correctly.

You would only need a `coordinate***` type if you were to try and pass `dinoPoints` as a reference to a function, where you somehow wanted to change what `dinoPoints` was pointing to, and allow any other function using `dinoPoints` to see the change ... but in this case it's a global variable, so that's not really needed...

Answer (score 1):

You're using an array of arrays of pointers to coordinates here (3 levels), but an array of arrays of coordinates (2 levels) would suffice.

Instead of this:

```
//dynamically allocates the number of polys in file to datastructure
dinoPoints = new coordinates**[numpolys];

for(int j = 0; j < numpolys; j++){  // read each polyline

    inStream >> numlines;  // read in number of lines in polyline

    dinoPoints[j] = new coordinates*[numlines]; // make an array of pointers
    for (int i = 0; i < numlines; i++){  // allocate each set of coords
        dinoPoints[j][i] = new coordinates;

        // read in specific point coordinates
        inStream >> dinoPoints[j][i].x >> dinoPoints[j][i].y;
    }
}
```

Just do:

```
// ** At the beginning of the file **
coordinates **dinoPoints;

// ** Inside the loadDino function **
//dynamically allocates the number of polys in file to datastructure
dinoPoints = new coordinates*[numpolys];

for(int j = 0; j < numpolys; j++){  // read each polyline

    inStream >> numlines;  // read in number of lines in polyline

    dinoPoints[j] = new coordinates[numlines]; // make an array of coordinates
    for (int i = 0; i < numlines; i++) {  // allocate each set of coords
        // read in specific point coordinates
        inStream >> dinoPoints[j][i].x >> dinoPoints[j][i].y;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick to your original data structure, just change the line for which the error was reported to

```
inStream >> dinoPoints[j][i]->x >> dinoPoints[j][i]->y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dinoPoints is a pointer to pointer to pointer, you need 3 indices to access a coordinate, not 2.

You are in C++ so why don't you use vector, or boost::multiarray.